# Is there any reference on the hardness of approximation for 2-partition problem?

Tags: np-hardness

I tried to look for some references but could not find any. I knew it is proved to be NP-complete via a transformation from Knapsack or 3DM problem. But I couldn't find a way to apply PCP theorem to get the hardness of approximation for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia page on the Partition problem: "...there are fully polynomial-time approximation schemes for the subset-sum problem, and hence for the partition problem as well". The references given there are
[Kellerer, Pferschy, Pisinger](http://books.google.com/?id=u5DB7gck08YC&pg=PA97) and [Martello, Toth](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1086874).

Comment: In fact, every problem that can be solved by a pseudopolynomial algorithm (including partition), that has an integer-valued objective function, and whose objective value is polynomial in unary encoding size [has an FPTAS](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~mlh/algkon/complexity.pdf). See Sect. 8.3 in V. Vazirani's *Approximation Algorithms*.

Comment: @Magnus: I think it is the other way - if the integer-valued objective function is polynomial in unary and the problem has an FPTAS, then it has a pseudopoly alg.

Comment: Indeed—that's also what I wrote in the note I linked to above. Got a bit mixed up here. Thanks.